# Unable to play video in avplayer with custom request

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avplayer

Hi am trying to send custom header with avplayer request so I had added a custom scheme like

```
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: "mycustomscheme://tungsten.aaplimg.com/VOD")!, options: nil)
```

because of this request fails and delegate method `shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource` is called.

In `shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource` am making a custom request and am recieving the data from server but avplayer is still not playing the file. Here is my code :

```
func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool {

    resourceLoader.delegateQueue?.async {

        var request: URLRequest? = loadingRequest.request
        request?.url = self.url

        // Add header
        request?.setValue(HeadersForWS.DeviceOS, forHTTPHeaderField: HeadersForWS.DeviceType)
        request?.setValue(Utility.getUserId(), forHTTPHeaderField:HeadersForWS.UserId )

        if let aRequest = request {

            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

            session.dataTask(with: aRequest as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in

                guard let data = data else {
                    try? loadingRequest.finishLoading()
                    return
                }


                loadingRequest.dataRequest?.respond(with: data)
                loadingRequest.finishLoading()

                }.resume()
        }

    }

    return true

}
```

If I save the data received to a file sample.mp4 and pull the file from app and then try to play then it plays means am receiving the video data properly. What may be the problem here??

Thanks in advance

Comment: is your server url is **HTTP**?

Comment: No its an https url